# Is ``torch.autograd.grad" differentiable for its internal variables?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, autograd

I have a network that incorporates a learnable gradient descent step and is implemented as follows:

---

**Implementation #1:**

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

def cal_grad(x, loss):
    v = torch.autograd.Variable(x, requires_grad=True)
    loss_v = loss(v)
    return torch.autograd.grad(loss_v, v, torch.ones_like(loss_v))[0]

class Net_autograd(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net_autograd, self).__init__()
        self.A = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(100, 50))
        self.rho = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1,))

    def forward(self, x_init, y):
        grad = cal_grad(x_init, lambda z: 0.5 * (z.mm(self.A) - y).pow(2).sum(dim=[1,]))  # calculate gradient implicitly (without giving its formula)
        x_hat = x_init - self.rho * grad
        return x_hat

net = Net_autograd()
x_init = torch.rand(10, 100, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.rand(10, 50, requires_grad=False)
x_gt = torch.rand(10, 100, requires_grad=False)

x_hat = net(x_init, y)

loss = (x_hat - x_gt).pow(2).mean()  # L2 loss
loss.backward()

print('A', net.A.grad)
print('rho', net.rho.grad)
print('x_init', x_init.grad)
```

---

It is not that common that I use a learnable matrix `self.A` to calculate gradient and obtain `x_hat`, in its forwarding process. I am confused by that why after `loss.backward()`, the gradient of parameter `self.A` is `None`?

And I re-implement the original network by explicitly giving the analytic gradient calculation formula, the parameter `self.A` can be successfully learned since `net.A.grad` will not be `None`:

---

**Implementation #2:**

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

class Net_explicit(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net_explicit, self).__init__()
        self.A = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(100, 50))
        self.rho = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1,))

    def forward(self, x_init, y):
        grad = (x_init.mm(self.A) - y).mm(self.A.t())  # calculate gradient explicitly
        x_hat = x_init - self.rho * grad
        return x_hat

net = Net_explicit()
x_init = torch.rand(10, 100, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.rand(10, 50, requires_grad=False)
x_gt = torch.rand(10, 100, requires_grad=False)

x_hat = net(x_init, y)

loss = (x_hat - x_gt).pow(2).mean()  # L2 loss
loss.backward()

print('A', net.A.grad)
print('rho', net.rho.grad)
print('x_init', x_init.grad)
```

---

I want to ask that:

1. The second implementation works well as my expectation, but why the first one does not train `self.A` (with `None` gradient)? I guess that the `torch.autograd.grad` itself may not be differentiable for its internal variables, since the external learnable gradient descent step size `self.rho` and input `x_init` obtain their own `grad`s.
2. To implement more complicated pipelines, in which `self.A` may be even a large network, what can I do to make the implementation **#1** works well as **#2** (i.e., to make `self.A` be trainable with `autograd` mechanisms)?
3. By the way, I am not sure if the `grad` of `x_init` calculated in the forwardings of **#1** and **#2** are identical or totally equal.  Could you please check this for me?

Note: The first dimensions of `x_init`, `y` and `x_gt`, with the size of 10, are the batch dimensions. The version of my `torch` is `1.7.1`, and the `torch.autograd.grad` does not have the parameter `is_grads_batched`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I solved this problem by modifying the returning code of function `cal_grad` to be:

```
    return torch.autograd.grad(loss_v, v, torch.ones_like(loss_v), create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]
```